# Duplicating a JavaFx group node loaded from FXML in run time

Tags: java, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I am trying duplicate a group node which i designed in scene builder. Then add the same to a vertical box below to the same node.

The group node contains a label, text field and a button. When i click the button it should add a duplicate group node below

I tried using 
FXCollections.copy(dest, src);
by passing the observable list into it. But the vbox says duplicate id.
If there are any good ideas. pls let me know.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but can't you just load the FXML file again?

Comment: I trying to duplicate a group node which I designed inside an FXML file. The group node will be item 0 in  a vbox, I wanna duplicate it and add it as item 2. The group node has a button textfield and label.  Currently I am using a separate FXML just to design the group node and adding it multiple times inside the vbox in the main FxML. Just wanna know, if we could duplicate that group node as that would be an easy task.

Comment: OK, so why can't you just load multiple instances from the FXML file? Perhaps it would help to post some code?

Comment: Yeah that is what I did eventually. But this doesn't look like an optimal solution. For just duplicating a group, why do I have to write a separate fxml with only the group. I have many more such groups. I felt I'm hard coding a bit

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to what the problem is. If you're "duplicating", you would just need a single FXML file that you load multiple times, no? If there are several that are different, then you have to code them differently in some way no matter how you do it. (If they're similar, you could have a single FXML that you load and then further configure in code.) Again, if you can create a simple example that demonstrates the problem, it might help.